# UIView animateWithDuration completion block interrupted by loop break;

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm encountering an interesting phenomena with Swift 1.2 and Xcode.  My familiarity with the language and library inner-workings are not sufficient to understand why this happens.  Perhaps someone can explain.  Consider the following code block:

```
static func hideSpinner(spinnerViewParent: UIViewController) {

    for thissubview in spinnerViewParent.view.subviews
    {
        if thissubview is SpinnerView {

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {(thissubview as! SpinnerView).alpha = 0.0}, completion: {completed in thissubview.removeFromSuperview();})

            break; //if you break, it will subvert and hijack the completion closure
        }
    }
}
```

SpinnerView is a simple subclass of a UIView which throws a spinner on screen to alert the user that the app is 'thinking'.  The hideSpinner function fades the SpinnerView out, and then removes it from the parent view.

The problem is, if you leave the break; in, the completion block of the animateWithDuration call will not execute properly.

If you comment out the break;, it works as intended.

Why?  Does breaking the loop somehow subvert and orphan the closure callback?  Why does removing the break; make it work as intended?

Comment: What do you mean by "not execute properly" / "hijack"?

Comment: @AaronBrager it doesn't execute the completion statement

Answer (score 0):

That's a weird one. What, exactly, does the animation do when you have a `break`? Leave the spinnerView inside it's superView?

Have you tried putting a `println()` inside your completion block to see if the code is executing?

If it is truly misbehaving then it's probably a compiler bug.

### EDIT:

Have you tried rewriting it using manual array indexing and a while...do loop with a boolean `done` flag? That would confirm that it's the break statement causing the problem.

Comment: Exactly the subview stays there.... it doesn't execute the .removeFromSuperview().  I'll have to try that do loop suggestion...